# TFS state based workflow

Tags: tfs

Is it possible in TFS that workitem can have two state options when created. For e.g 
I have a requirement in which when bug is created it can either be DEV state or CCB state.
But I am not able to figure out the way how to do this. All I was able to do is to put one redundant initial state as "New" to start with. And from New state I can either go to DEV or I choose CCB.

Any inputs will be really appreciated.

Thanks,

Mayur

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mayur - it's not possible.  You can choose a different Reason at the time of creation (eg:  Build Failure, Regression, etc), but a work item only has one initial state.

Comment: Thanks for this! I will see if I can choose different reasons to serve my purpose.